# jQuery LightBox- Disable lightbox on a particular image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am using this [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) plugin.

Some of my images might be missing their full size image urls.

In that case, I want to disable lightbox on them.

They are dynamic, so I don't know beforehand which urls might be missing.

Could you help me pls?

Comment: can you show some code you are using..

Comment: I have an image rotator . There is only one image at a time , which is replaced on clicking next . So I cannot do away with the links , only manipulate the 'href' of the link. And I am applying lightbox on individual images.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer Colorbox over Lightbox, it has a couple of more nice features. http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

For instance, you can act on several events (callbacks), like onOpen or onLoad. There you can check if the image you want to show is valid, and if not, just cancel the event. See the Colorbox documentation for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since LightBox is attached to the link, not to the image itself, you can do that easyly by simply not puting a link to the fulsize image if it is missing. How to do that is a different matter, depending on how you get the images (just reading the folder of from the DataBase).

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to generate that rotator?